# row_pop() function in pysqlite?

Tags: python, database, pysqlite

Need to *get one row from a table, and delete the same row*.

It does not matter which row it is. The function should be generic, so the column names are unknown, and there are no identifiers. (Rows as a whole can be assumed to be unique.)

The resulting function would be like a pop() function for a stack, except that the order of elements does not matter.

**Possible solutions:**

- Delete into a temporary table.
  (Can this be done in pysqlite?)
- `Get *` with 1 as limit, and the `Delete *` with 1 as limit.
  (Is this safe if there is just one user?)
- Get one row, then delete with a `WHERE` clause that compares the whole row.
  (Can this be done in pysqlite?)

Suggestions?

Comment: Well. every table in a sqlite has a rowid. Select one and delete it?

Comment: @Max Yep, that did it. Pretty straight forward, but I did not know it existed. Thanks!

Comment: I'll change my comment to an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. every table in a sqlite has a rowid. Select one and delete it?